# How to print each page of a pdf with different page setup?

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, printer

Say I have a pdf with 10pages.

In page 1, I want to print it in single side using tray 1 (A4 white paper).

In page 2-6, I want to print them in double side using tray 1(A4 white paper).

In page 7, I want to print it in single side using tray 2(A4 green paper).

In page 8-10, I want to print them in double side using tray 1(A4 white paper).

Usually, I do this by printing them pages by pages which is a tedious work.

Is there any software that can set the print setup for each page and print all pages with different print setup by one click?

Comment: There is no software to do this. The only way to do that is to use multiple print commands. You can automate it with a script if you like. Have a look at Autohotkey. Unless you always want the same tray arrangement, you may want to put the tray details in a text file and have Autohotkey read them.

Comment: aside from the green paper issue, the rest could most easily be done by inserting blank pages; after page 1, 6 & 7 as they are currently numbered. Then the whole thing could just be printed double-sided.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Print&Share](http://www.printandshare.info):
Basic example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iXuU4b5mh4&list=PLDF2C2AD95B2B2FC2&index=35

If you look in the manual in chapter 10: "Annexe 10: Dynamic custom page ranges" you can use formulas to calculate some page ranges: http://www.printandshare.info/downloads/Print&Share%20-%20Operating%20Manual%20EN%202.8.3.pdf

From the [Practical Guide](http://www.printandshare.info/download):

**Document from two trays**

```
In this case, we print by one click the whole document two times by taking the paper from two different trays:

Please follow the steps to build this case:  
- Create your profile with a channel with print functionality. 
- Go to the channel configuration by clicking on the printer icon. 
- Click on the [Page definitions…] button. 
- Add two lines by the [Add] button. 
- Select in the first line the Page Range, All pages and select Paper Source Tray 1 to get your document out of tray 1. 
- Select in the second line the Page Range, All pages and select Paper Source Tray 2 to get your document out of tray 2. 
- Set the option at the bottom to [Extra pages sorted by page ranges (R1{1,2} R2{1,2}, …)] 
- Close the dialogs by clicking [OK] buttons.
```

**Pages from different trays:**

```
In this case, we print by one click some page of the document by using different trays:

In the example we will take page one of the document out of Tray 1 and the other pages from paper source Tray 2. 

You will get by this case an example of the usage of the Paper source feature. 

- Create your profile with a channel with print functionality. 
- Go to the channel configuration by clicking on the printer icon. 
- Click the [Page Definitions] button.  
- Add two lines by the [Add] button. 
- Select in the first line the Page Range, First page and select Paper Source Tray 1 to get your first page of your document out of tray 1. 
- Select in the second line the Page Range, 2 - LastPage and select Paper Source Tray 2 to get your second page and all other pages of your document out of tray 2. 
- Set the option at the bottom to [No extra pages (1,2,3,…)] 
- Close the dialogs by clicking [OK] buttons.
```

Comment: It's best that you summarize the linked content. As it stands, this is essentially a link-only answer—such answers would not be very useful if the linked content goes down, and may be misread as spam.

Comment: i've added the information from the documentation on how to create this very basically.

Comment: +1, much better. That's the kind of answer we'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

To give a more complete answer: Xerox Freeflow software does this very nicely, but it's only for their larger production printers.  You didn't mention which types of printers you have access to, so I thought I'd offer.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but the typical way to do this without specialized software is to:

1. Use any of the available PDF editors (software you may have on your computer or one of the many web services), to add a blank page after each of the two single sided pages.  You have odd numbers of double-sided pages, so also add a blank page after pages 6 and 10.
2. Pre-stack the paper to insert a green sheet as sheet 5.  If you are printing multiple sets, insert another green sheet after every 6 white sheets following the first green sheet (and leave extra white sheets after the last set; you can just put the stack on top of the white paper in tray 1).
3. Print the entire document double-sided from tray 1.